# Android JNI GetMethodID for sharedPreferences.getString

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to get a string from sharedPreferences on Android from C++ code using JNI. I can successfully get the MethodID for getBoolean with this code:

```
jmethodID getBooleanMethodID = JEnv->GetMethodID(sharedPreferencesClass, "getBoolean", "(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Z");
```

The getBoolean function is defined in Java as getBoolean(String key, boolean defValue)

But I can't figure out how to correctly format the GetMethodID arguments for getString.
The getString function is defined in Java as getString(String key, String defValue)

I've tried:

```
jmethodID getStringMethodID = JEnv->GetMethodID(sharedPreferencesClass, "getString", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String)");
```

Can someone provide the correct way to format the argument param for getString?

Comment: You should never ever have to write Java internal signatures yourself. Extract them  from the output of `javap -s` instead.

Comment: @botje Can you give the specifics for the javap -s search? What would the class be?

Comment: The output of `javap -cp $ANDROID_SDK/platforms/android-30/android.jar -s android.content.SharedPreferences` contains the signature of `getString`. Assumes `$ANDROID_SDK` is set correctly, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format turned out to be:

```
jmethodID getStringMethodID = JEnv->GetMethodID(sharedPreferencesClass, "getString", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;");
```

There were a couple issues with my original attemps. First, the second String arg inside the brackets needed a semi-colon. Then I needed to add the return type, also a String, and be sure that it had a semi-colon at the end too.